# Bat file service runs many times

Tags: batch-file

**I have created a bat file to start a Ruby service**

working code is:

```
ruby C:\folder\Projects\folder\folder\script\server
```

It **works fine** when I open a command prompt ,paste it and run.

but **not working** when I created a bat file of it.

bat content is

`ruby C:\folder\Projects\folder\folder\script\server
pause`

when I run that bat file, it not working as expected. It runs multiple as shown below.
[image]

Please help me to resolve it.

Comment: I could bet that you named your script `ruby.bat`. Use a different name!

Comment: Yep :) It worked.. How will the rename fix the issue ?

Comment: See my answer below. If this answer solved your problem, you may select is as Best Answer (and perhaps also up vote it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Batch file must have a name different than the process you want to run in it. In this case, the Batch file must *not* be named `ruby.bat`, because in this case, the line:

```
ruby C:\folder\Projects\folder\folder\script\server
```

placed in the Batch file imply a recursive invocation of itself...